# How to properly setup authentication-based navigation

Tags: navigation, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have been trying to figure out the correct way to setup navigation through my app based on the value of `FirebaseAuth` (i.e: navigating the users only after they had logged in)

So I have created a scenario where I have 3 classes, I will start by listing out my test case and then will discuss the problems I am facing at the end.

`User` Class is the very first page in my app, it draws it is widgets after checking if there is a `currentUser` or not

```
    class User extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _UserState createState() => new _UserState();
    }

    class _UserState extends State<User> {
       FirebaseUser _user;


      @override
      initState() {
        super.initState();
        _checkUser();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _user == null? new SignInPage(): new HomePage();
      }

      _checkUser ()async {
        FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        setState((){
          this._user = user;
        });

      }
    }
```

When the app launches for the very first time, it loads `SignInPage` since there is no user data:

```
class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInPageState createState() => new _SignInPageState();
}

class _SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();


   _handleSignIn() async{

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(!user.isAnonymous);
    assert(await user.getToken() != null);
    print (user);

         }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Sign In"),
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: new Container(),
            backgroundColor: new Color.fromARGB(255,17,165,137)),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child:
                new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[new RaisedButton(
                          child: new Container(
                              child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                    child: new Image(
                                      image: new NetworkImage(
                                          "https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Logos//google_logo1600.png"),
                                    ),
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0)),
                                new Text("Login with Google", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent)),
                              ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center)),
                          onPressed: (){_handleSignIn().whenComplete((){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Home");});}

                          ,color: Colors.white),
                      ],),
                    new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      )


                  ],
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }


}
```

This is my `HomePage` class, which is only accessible if the authentication is verified; my Home contains a `RaisedButton` on the center, and has a `Text`child of the `displayName` of the current user, and an `onPressed()` action that calls the `_signOut()` method and returns to `SignInage`

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => new _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  FirebaseUser _currentUser;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myUser();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Hello:)"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(child: new Text(_currentUser.displayName),
            onPressed: (){_signOut().whenComplete((){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SignInPage");});})
      ),
    );
  }
  _signOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

    await _googleSignIn.signOut();

    return "Signed out";
  }

   _myUser()async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    setState((){
      this._currentUser = user;
    });
  }


}
```

**The Problem:**

1. When the app starts for the first time it loads `SignInPage` as normal, however when I successfully sign in to my google account, it freezes without navigating me because `displayName was called on Null`, from my understanding that flutter did not have enough time to prepare user data before the navigation occurs, I am guessing this because of what happens in points 2 and 3.
2. When restarting the app and preserving the previous auth session, the app automatically starts with the `Home` page, and the displayName is correctly displayed.
3. In the same session,I click the `RaisedButton` which signs out and correctly navigating me back to `SignInPage`, I try to log in again and we are back to the main problem, it tries to navigate me to my `Home` before the `displayName` is obtained.

This is how I understand the problem, so what am I doing wrong here and how to design the correct flow?

**P.S:** the reason I want to do this is because I want to use some data of `currentUser` in my `HomePage`.

**Update:**

the console prints the following:

```
'package:test/SignInScreen.dart': Failed assertion: line 26: 'user.email != null': is not true.
```

This is in `assert` statements in `_handleSignIn`.

I have also tried to create a pre-Home page, same problem occurs, I am not sure what is wrong now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` as the `future` argument. Then in your `builder` method if the `hasData` property of the `AsyncSnapshot` is false, you know that the widget is still loading and you should show a placeholder. Once the `Future` completes, you can use the `data` property of the `AsyncSnapshot` to obtain the `FirebaseUser`.

Alternatively, you could check if `_currentUser` is null in your `build` method and return an empty container since the user info isn't available yet.

Comment: I still get the same problem, but let's say if hasData is false, then how to hold the loading of the Home page until it is true, what kind of a place holder that will redirect me to my Home when currentUser() is finally ready.

if you check the updated section in the post, you will find that I even tried to place a dummy page right after SignInPage just to get things ready for my HomePage, and still the same problem.

Comment: and when we check _currentUser if null, we know it is null, at least for the current run and until I restart the app, this is the core of the problem.

Comment: Please, have you managed to reproduce the same problem or am I missing something ?

Comment: My mistake was trying to use `FutureBuilder` and while using a state for the widget at the same time, it works now fine. I initially thought I can use `FutureBuilder` and a `State` interchangeably, but apparently I can not. Especially with `State` I can reuse my `currentUser` data from one class in other class instead of using `FutureBuilder` for each class that needs to access this data. Thanks anyways for always being so helpful.

Comment: You can take the user from the AsyncSnapshot data and pass it as a constructor argument to other widgets. Really what you want is more of a Stream than a Future and that's an addition to the API that I've been considering.